# Find destination position of ball

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, physics

How to move the ball dependent on touch angle and make the ball reflect if it touches the wall?

```
CGFloat diffX = ballImg.position.x - tchLoc.x;
CGFloat diffY = ballImg.position.y - tchLoc.y;
CGFloat angleRadian = atan2f(diffY, diffX);

float angleDegrees=CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadian);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you have taken your ball as a sprite. so in touchesBegan you will get the touch location and then you can use that location points in CCMoveTo action to move your ball which is a sprite.....

Comment: i need to move the ball as  a sprite to touch position angle ? and if the ball touch on the wall it should be reflected