# how to create bubble shooter game in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

pls any one help me . I am working on a project like bubble shooter,but i have no idea.now i have to find only touch position angle .

```
    float radians=ccpToAngle(ccpSub(tchPoint, ballImg.position));
    float degrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES( radians);
```

pls anybody help me ,and give an idea to implement this project.

Comment: Double-post of [Find destination position of ball](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159785/find-destination-position-of-ball)

Comment: @veer it is not a place to talk personally.here to share knowledge alone,if u have any doubt u post your questions here.

Answer (score 1):

To find the angle of a vector v (CGPoint v) use atan2 (or atan2f function):

float angle = atan2(v.y, v.x);

The angle will be in radiance, counting from x axes.

Comment: i suggest you to ask another question and specify details

Answer (score 0):

You already have the ball position (x,y), touch position (x',y') and the  use angle (slope) and voila, you have a vector.